# node_modules/@zerohouse/router-tab/zerohouse-router-tab.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported! after upgrading angular 8 to angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LcmV.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serveapp": "ng serve --configuration=uat",
    "buildapp": "babel --plugins @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js -o node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js && node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --source-map=false --base-href / --prod --aot --build-optimizer=false",
    "buildappPROD": "babel --plugins @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js -o node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js && node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --source-map=false --base-href / --prod --aot --build-optimizer=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "node src/assets/js/patch.js",
    "ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist ngsw-config.json",
    "ngsw-copy": "copy node_modules\\@angular\\service-worker\\ngsw-worker.js dist",
    "build-ngsw": "babel --plugins @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js -o node_modules/bpmnlint/lib/linter.js && node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --source-map=false --base-href / --prod --aot --build-optimizer=false --named-chunks && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.13",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^2.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "2.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.15",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^12.0.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "^17.4.51",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^3.1.6",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.7",
    "@types/topojson-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@zerohouse/router-tab": "0.0.7",
    "aes-js": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-disable-browser-back-button": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-highcharts": "^9.0.2",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.3.0",
    "angular-text-input-autocomplete": "^0.3.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.2.1",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.11.1",
    "angular2gridster": "^8.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bn.js": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bpmn-js": "5.1.2",
    "bpmn-js-bpmnlint": "^0.15.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.33.0",
    "bpmn-js-token-simulation": "^0.10.0",
    "bpmnlint": "^6.4.0",
    "bpmnlint-plugin-playground": "file:./plugin",
    "buffer": "^5.6.0",
    "built-in-math-eval": "^0.3.0",
    "camunda-bpmn-moddle": "^4.3.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "d3": "^5.12.0",
    "diagram-js-minimap": "^2.0.3",
    "exact-math": "^2.2.0",
    "file-drops": "^0.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "flat-angular": "^1.6.0",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "highcharts": "^8.0.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "keyboardevent-key-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.8",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.8",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.9",
    "ng2-carouselamos": "^4.1.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.11",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.4.9",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "notevil": "^1.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "sodium-plus": "^0.9.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.0",
    "topojson-client": "^3.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.13",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.9.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/topojson": "^3.2.2",
    "ack-angular-webcam": "^1.10.0",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.70",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Include errors directly in your post, not images

Comment: sure i am new so dont have much idea from next i ll do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@zerohouse/router-tab** isn't compatible with angular 9, you have to install [@cativo/router-tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cativo/router-tab) to get it work.

Comment: is there any other solutions for zerohose ? i am having this module in lots of places

Comment: i am getting same error

Comment: ERROR in Can't export value MatTabsModule in D:/STAR_UX_25TH OCT/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts from RouterTabModule in D:/STAR_UX_25TH OCT/node_modules/@zerohouse/router-tab/zerohouse-router-tab.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!

Comment: @SantoshKumar according to github repo, there is still an open issue with angular9 https://github.com/zerohouse/router-tab/issues/9

Comment: working for me thanks